# How to use key number as a value at the array?

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

I have an array, where every item has a few parameters. One of the parameters is a hyperlink with the ID of that item. And I need that ID to be a key for that item value.

I've already tried something like this:

```
function item_preview($database)
 {
    foreach($database as $key=> $value)
    {
      $one= $key;
    }
      return $one;
}

$database= [
[
    'name'=> 'item_one',
    'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_one.jpg',
    'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id='.item_preview($database).'',
    'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
],
[
    'name'=> 'item_two',
    'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_two.jpg',
    'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id='.item_preview($database).'',
    'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
],
];
```

and what i need is...

```
 $database= [
 [
    'name'=> 'item_one',
    'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_one.jpg',
    'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id= here should be key number',
    'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
],
[
    'name'=> 'item_two',
    'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_two.jpg',
    'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id= here should be key number',
    'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
],
];
```

So I need id to be key of that item. So first  item id=0; second item id=1;....

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: No, i take Dylan Hamilton advice and did it with $starting_index++ and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
$startingIndex = 0;

$database= [
[
    'name'=> 'item_one',
    'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_one.jpg',
    'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id='.$startingIndex++.'',
    'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
],
[
    'name'=> 'item_two',
    'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_two.jpg',
    'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id='.$startingIndex++.'',
    'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
],
```

That would result in id being `0` for the first entry, `1` for the second, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can just define the key and use it in the href:

```
$database= [
0=>[
    'name'=> 'item_one',
    'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_one.jpg',
    'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id=0',
    'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
],
1=>[
    'name'=> 'item_two',
    'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_two.jpg',
    'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id=1',
    'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
]];
```

Or, after defining your array, just walk it and append the key:

```
$database= [
[
    'name'=> 'item_one',
    'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_one.jpg',
    'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id=',
    'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
],
[
    'name'=> 'item_two',
    'img_src'=> 'pictures/item_two.jpg',
    'preview_href'=> 'item_site.php?id=',
    'description'=> 'This product is.....' ,
]];

array_walk($database, function(&$v, $k){ $v['preview_href'] .= $k; });
```